# Could not find artifact in NexusRepository (Using Maven Proxy repository)

Tags: maven, nexus, nexus3

We are behind corp proxy. I have installed Sonatype Nexus repository manager.

Tried to setup npm and maven proxy repositories following this link [Maven and NPM Proxy repositories](https://guides.sonatype.com/repo3/quick-start-guides/proxying-maven-and-npm/) . NPM proxy setup worked well and test projects passed.
But getting issues with Maven proxy setup.Created a test project which is using maven and it is running into issues.The dependencies are not being downloaded.

**Things I did**
1) Setup HTTP and HTTPS Proxy in Nexus ( since we are behind Corp proxy)

2) Created a Maven proxy and Maven Hosted repository and grouped them via Maven-public repository named maven-public.

3) Created ~/.m2/settings.xml with below contents

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
   <mirrors>
    <mirror>
     <id>NexusRepository</id>
     <url>http://nexusrepohost:8080/repository/maven-public/</url>
     <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
   </mirrors>
   <proxies>
    <proxy>
      <id>http</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>proxyserver</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <username>proxyusername</username>
      <password>proxypassword</password>
      <nonProxyHosts>|127.0.0.1|nexusrepohost</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
    <proxy>
      <id>https</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>https</protocol>
      <host>proxyserver</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <username>proxyusername</username>
      <password>proxypassword</password>
      <nonProxyHosts>|127.0.0.1|nexusrepohost</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
</settings>
```

**The Error message is**

```
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:2.18.1 in NexusRepository (http://nexusrepohost:8080/repository/maven-public/) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:2.18.1 in NexusRepository (http://nexusrepohost:8080/repository/maven-public/)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve (DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:181)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:244)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecution (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:168)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecutions (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:130)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:144)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.BuilderCommon.resolveBuildPlan (BuilderCommon.java:96)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:2.18.1 in NexusRepository (http://nexusrepohost:8080/repository/maven-public/)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:413)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:247)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve (DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:181)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:244)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecution (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:168)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecutions (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:130)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:144)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.BuilderCommon.resolveBuildPlan (BuilderCommon.java:96)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:2.18.1 in NexusRepository (http://nexusrepohost:8080/repository/maven-public/)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed (ArtifactTransportListener.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run (RunnableErrorForwarder.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:642)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:247)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve (DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:181)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:244)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecution (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:168)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecutions (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:130)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:144)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.BuilderCommon.resolveBuildPlan (BuilderCommon.java:96)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

**NOTE:**

1) Definitely not a proxy issue,because npm tet worked fine and it downloaded artifacts from NPM registry. I can see them in Nexus.

Any setting I am missing?

Comment: What happens if you go to http://nexusrepohost:8080/repository/maven-public/ in a web browser (or curl, netcat, etc.)

Comment: curl andbrowser gives me this message "This maven2 group repository is not directly browseable at this URL."

Comment: I'd try mvn with the -X parameter to get debug logging. Also, you've got a HTTP and HTTPS proxy defined but only seem to be using HTTP?

Comment: The log in original post is from a mvn -X execution. Not sure about why http is only used. Nexus allows us to set both https and http proxy. Same is set in maven settings.So possible that  choosing http / https is done by maven ?

Comment: That nonProxyHosts value looks wrong, there shouldn't be a leading '|': https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html

Comment: @rseddon You are right. It was a typo while copying the contents to this forum. Settings.xml is good. Still the issue exists.